# html page return by nuxt.renderRoute has unwanted redirect to 404

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

**Context**

I have many pages, and for some pages I need to generate html for an api call. Here I use nuxt.renderRoute to do the job.

So someone can call my api and display the page like the following:

```
fetch("article-preview-api", {pageTitle: 'Preview article'})
.then(res => res.text())
.then(html => {
  var previewWindow = window.open("","");
  previewWindow.document.write(html); 
})
```

**The problem**

Now the problem is when I open the html file,the page will automatically redirect to 404 page.

**Steps to reproduce**

Here is the demo code
https://github.com/shaoyulan/nuxt_generate_route_demo

1. run npm build
2. run node server.js
3. open open-this-demo.html with vscode live server

**What is expected ?**

Open open-this-demo.html and stay at that page.
[This is correct page screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18SpO.jpg)

**What is actually happening?**

Open open-this-demo.html and got redirected to 404 page.

This is unwanted redirect's screenshot:

[image: This is unwanted redirect's screenshot]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you're using Nuxt why are you still using the VSCode dev server?

Comment: @code I have update my question. The html are meant to be used on different website.
Thanks for your reply!